# Usando o ReportView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Gostaria de uma ajuda. Estou usando o `ReportView` para gerar um relatório a partir do id passado como parâmetro:

```
public ActionResult Relatorio(Guid id)
{
    LocalReport relatorio = new LocalReport();

    //Caminho onde o arquivo do Report Viewer está localizado
    relatorio.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report/RelatorioCliente.rdlc");
    //Define o nome do nosso DataSource e qual rotina irá preenche-lo, no caso, nosso método criado anteriormente RepositorioPedido.SelecionaPedido(codPedido)));

    relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSetCliente", _clienteRepositorio.BuscarTodos().AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(c=>c.ClienteId == id)));

    string reportType = "PDF";
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string fileNameExtension;

    string deviceInfo =
      "<DeviceInfo>" +
      " <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
      " <PageWidth>9in</PageWidth>" +
      " <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
      " <MarginTop>0.7in</MarginTop>" +
      " <MarginLeft>2in</MarginLeft>" +
      " <MarginRight>2in</MarginRight>" +
      " <MarginBottom>0.7in</MarginBottom>" +
      "</DeviceInfo>";

    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streams;
    byte[] bytes;

    //Renderiza o relatório em bytes
    bytes = relatorio.Render(
    reportType,
    deviceInfo,
    out mimeType,
    out encoding,
    out fileNameExtension,
    out streams,
    out warnings);

    return File(bytes, mimeType);
}
```

Mas na hora que vou gerar o relatório, ele da um erro na linha:

```
relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSetCliente", _clienteRepositorio.BuscarTodos().AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(c=>c.ClienteId == id)));
```

E diz que:

> O objeto de fonte de dados do relatório deve ser do tipo
>   System.Data.DataTable, System.Collections.IEnumerable ou
>   System.Web.UI.IDataSource.

Alguém poderia me da uma ajuda. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

O erro é bem claro: deve ser passado como fonte de dados algum objeto que implemente `IEnumerable`, `IDataSource`, ou que seja `DataTable`.

O comando `FirstOrDefault()` que você está usando irá trazer apenas uma instância `T` de cliente, que não implementa nada do que está contratado. Você deve "envelopar" essa instância de cliente num `DataSet` ou `IEnumerable` por mais que será exibido apenas um registro.

Você teria que criar um `List<Cliente>` e adicionar esse único cliente na lista, e passar para o relatório.

Eu tenho a seguinte implementação para isso com ReportViewer em WPF, a ideia é a mesma:

```
private void InicializarRelatorio(string nomeRelatorio, Dictionary<string, IEnumerable> dados)
    {
        //percorre o dicionario para adicionar as fontes de dados no relatorio
        foreach (var dado in dados)
        {
            ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
            reportDataSource.Name = dado.Key; //nome do DataSet no .rdlc
            reportDataSource.Value = dado.Value; // objeto(lista) de dados
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
        }

        //carrega o relatorio que deve estar na pasta do executavel. o arquivo rdlc deve estar CopyToLocal
        reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Relatorios\" + nomeRelatorio;
        reportViewer.RefreshReport();
    }

    private void btnFichaCliente_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ClienteBusiness business = new ClienteBusiness())
        {
            int codigoCliente = Convert.ToInt32(cboClientes.SelectedValue);
            var cliente = business.RelatorioFichaCliente(codigoCliente);

            if (cliente.Count > 0)
            {
                Dictionary<string, IEnumerable> dicDados = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable>();
                dicDados.Add("ClienteDataSet", cliente);

               InicializarRelatorio("RelCliente.rdlc", dicDados);
            }
        }
    }
```